# Pagination in Oracle without specifying all columns

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I've seen many examples of pagination like what's shown below.  However, I want to use the same query for many different tables. Is there a way to use this technique without having to specify the column names. Ideally, some way to select * as well as the added row_number column?

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnName1 ASC) AS rownumber, ColumnName1, ColumnName2
   FROM TableName
   ) AS foo
WHERE rownumber BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to specify the column(s) that you want to order by in the analytic function.  Beyond that, however, you can do

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               row_number() over (order by column1 ASC) rnk
          FROM tableName t)
 WHERE rnk BETWEEN 10 and 20
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That was perfect.  Yeah, I'll figure out some way to pick a column to order by, but that shouldn't be a problem.  Sorry if this was a relatively simple question, I'm not too familiar with SQL and oracle etc..